# How to write shell sort on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, shellsort

I'm trying to write a shellsort on Node.js like on the book Algorithms, 4th ed. Sedgewick, Wayne. There all the examples written on Java.

Here is my module:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = (function() {

  function sort(array) {
    let size = array.length;
    let h = 1;
    while(h < size/3) {
      h = h * 3 + 1;
    }
    while(h >= 1) {
      for(let i = h; i < size; i++) {
        for(let j = i; j >= h && less(array, j, j-h); j = j-h) {
          exch(array, j, j-h);
        }
      }
      h = h/3;
    }
  }

  function less(array, i, min) {
    return array[i] < array[min];
  }

  function exch(array, i, min) {
    let temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[min];
    array[min] = temp;
  }

  return {
    sort: sort
  };

})();
```

I use mocha and chai for testing with this function:

```
function isSorted(array) {
  for(let i = 1, size = array.length; i < size; i++) {
    if (array[i] < array[i-1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

and shell sort not working: [mocha test screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTBhF.png)

Comment: do you need your own sort function or you need a sort function to sort number?

Comment: I just don't understand why function `sort` in my module not working. It is the same as in book. You can see original implementation here:
[shell in java](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/Shell.java.html)

Comment: on module.export you are returning the function. But the function is not returning the sorted array. Instead of finding the bug further,  I have tried the algorithm too. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `h` may become a floating point number if you use `h = h / 3`. Try `h = Math.floor(h / 3);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Implementation of shell sort algorithm in Javascript

```
function shellSort(arr){
    
    var len  = arr.length;
    var gapSize =  Math.floor(len/2);
 
    while(gapSize > 0){
        for(var i = gapSize; i < len; i++) {
 
            var temp = arr[i];
            var j = i;
 
            while(j >= gapSize && arr[j - gapSize] > temp) {
                arr[j] = arr[j - gapSize];
                j -= gapSize;
            }
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
        gapSize = Math.floor(gapSize/2);
    }
    return arr;
}

function isSorted(array) {
  for(let i = 1, size = array.length; i < size; i++) {
    if (array[i] < array[i-1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

 
var randomArray = [45,86,3,5,97,95,4,24,7,88,93,27,45,90,54,89,74,5,90,73,74,857,834,8394,4231,485,32,54,674,12];
var mySortedArray = shellSort(randomArray);

console.log(mySortedArray);
console.log(isSorted(mySortedArray));
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 12, 24, 27, 32, 45, 45, 54, 54, 73, 74, 74, 86, 88, 89, 90, 90, 93, 95, 97, 485, 674, 834, 857, 4231, 8394]
true
```